# Distributing padding in between input fields on simple HTML Form

Tags: css, padding, forms, spacing

I have a simple HTML form connected to my CSS page, and I would like for the form to appear aesthetically pleasing on other monitors. However, I can not figure out a way for buttons and the input boxes to be at a certain spot of the form comparative to the screen (i.e. submit button 5% from the bottom, each input field fills has 5% padding in between, input fields fill the form on the screen regardless of monitor size).  I have successfully set the max width and height of the actual form, but can not figure out what to do with the content on the inside.

To sum up, when I pull up my website on other monitors, the text fields can look too small and there is large white space below the submit button. I would like to see if there is a way for everything to be spaced out as evenly as possible.

```css
/* Form CSS */

.form-style-5{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    max-width: 60%;
    height: 83%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}
.form-style-5:after{
    opacity: 1;
}
.form-style-5 fieldset{
    border: none;
}
.form-style-5 legend {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-style-5 label {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"],
.form-style-5 input[type="date"],
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"],
.form-style-5 input[type="email"],
.form-style-5 input[type="location"],
.form-style-5 input[type="number"],
.form-style-5 input[type="search"],
.form-style-5 input[type="time"],
.form-style-5 input[type="url"],
.form-style-5 textarea,
.form-style-5 select {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 7px;
    height: 6%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    background-color: #e8eeef;
    color:#8a97a0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="date"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="email"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="number"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="search"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="time"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="location"]:focus,
.form-style-5 textarea:focus,
.form-style-5 select:focus{
    background: #d2d9dd;
}
.form-style-5 select{
    -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
    height:35px;
}
.form-style-5 .number {
    background: red;
    color: #FCFBE3;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 4px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.form-style-5 input[type="submit"],
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 39px 10px 39px;
    color: #FCFBE3;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: normal;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"]:hover,
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]:hover{
    background: #b30000;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-style-5">
    <form action="send-sms.php" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><span class="number">1</span> Your Information</legend>
            <input type="text" name="field1" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *">
            <input type="email" name="field2" id="contact"placeholder="Contact Information (Email, Phone Number, etc.) *">
            <input type="location" name="field3" id="location" placeholder="Your Location (i.e. McNutt, Hodge Hall, exact address, etc.)*">
            <input type="text" name="field4" id="misc" placeholder="Miscellaneous Information That May Be Important"></textarea>
            <label for="job">Urgency:</label>
            <select id="job" name="field5">
                <optgroup label="Urgency level: just for us to prioritize properly">
                    <option value="Not Urgent">Low (ETA: Up to an hour)</option>
                    <option value="reading">Normal (ETA: Up to 45 mins)</option>
                    <option value="boxing">Critical (ETA: ASAP!)</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend><span class="number">2</span>Task that needs completion</legend>
            <input type="text" id="task" name="field6" placeholder="Let Us Know How We Can Help!*"></input>
        </fieldset>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="push();validateForm();"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You could give your inputs sizes in `vmin` rather than `px`... However, I don't see any serous problems with what it looks like.

Comment: It looks fine on my laptop and it may even look OK on your screen, but once some other client tries to pull it up on a larger screen, the input fields do not expand accordingly (i.e. each input box 8% of the form on screen, etc.). Thanks for your comment Mr. Lister.